# Ubuntu runs super slow

Tags: 14.04, performance, intel-cpu

I have an Acer Aspire computer that contains:

- Intel Atom CPU 1.33 GHz x 2
- 2.0 GB RAM
- Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
- Disk 243.9 GB

I thought that Ubuntu would run faster than Windows 7, so I installed Ubuntu 14.04. The result was terrible, it runs super slow, even the animation of closing a window runs in slow motion, about 1 FPS. I know its not the best PC, but it stands on the recommended requirements and still works slow as hell.

Any ideas why it is happening, and how to fix it? I thought it was maybe due to power saving mode being on, but I can't find the way to check it.

Comment: It's your graphics - your CPU is handling all of the graphics load (the llvmpipe) - if there is not a graphics driver available for your system you should probably think of one of the less graphics intensive versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using a lightweight and so more ugly display manager, try LXDE or XFCE. Maybe even GNOME works better. If it still runs slow with lxde, then something in the system is really slowing... but I have no idea what...

In case you don't know:

Install lxde with minimal adaption:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-core
```

...or only the lxde package:

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

To install xfce:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

And for the pure gnome:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core
```

Comment: since im super new on this OS i bearly know to explore my own files, i will appriciate if you will add some more information about what you wrote...

Answer (score 0):

Try Fresh installation of Ubuntu Varient Xubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn : Fast and Responsive

[Some Information about Xubuntu](http://ubuntuportal.com/2014/11/xubuntu-14-10-utopic-unicorn.html)

Comment: thanks for your help im trying now installing a parallel OS Xubuntu and i will compare them for performance

Answer (score 0):

Ah, and maybe you want to check first what steals the most power. Open the System Monitor (type it into Unity Dash or run it by <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or in a terminal with `gnome-system-monitor`). What is used most? RAM? CPU? Then go to the processes and order them by RAM/CPU usage. Which are on the top?

If you can't find it and my previous answer doesn't work or fit you, I don't know how to help, sorry...

Comment: You may annotate keyboard keys in the text with the <kbd> tag, e.g. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: @meskobalazs Thank you, didn't know that before. I am pretty new, at least to _writing_ posts...

Comment: so i tried what you suggested adn these are the results:
the memory useage is 455MB/2GB
the CPU useage is:
CPU1:83%~
CPU2: 94%~
i have to say that i have no programs running on background...
and in processes the only processes that use CPU is compiz that use 10%~ and the system monitor itself that takes 13%~.
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `Gallium on llvmpipe` part. This means, that instead using the *intel* driver, your laptop is basically rendering *everything* on the (very slow) CPU, that's why it crawls so badly. I can't really help with fixing the driver issue, I can only suggest using a desktop environment which does not need 3D acceleration, as @Peter Nerlich has suggested (personally I recommend XFCE, to me, LXDE always felt like an eyesore).

You could share with us the exact CPU you are using, maybe another solution exists for you. I am guessing it uses the **Intel GMA 500** (codename Poulsbo) chipset, which has the infamous PowerVR graphics core.

Another possible solution is trying out the older, **12.04** release of Ubuntu. I have a Samsung N150 netbook, with similar hardware, it works without much hassle - though I have only OpenGL 1.4 "thanks" to the pathetic GPU.

Comment: but if i do want to fix the driver issue what can i do?
thanks!

Comment: First we will need the exact chipset, then google around :)

Comment: how do i found what is my exact chipset?

Comment: The model number of the laptop should be good

Answer (score 0):

I think this must be a drivers issue, as on paper, Ubuntu should be more lightweight than Windows 7. Have you looked for other drivers yet? Go to "Additional drivers" and select a other driver.

Comment: AFAIK there are no closed-source graphics drivers for Intel-based computers...

Comment: @meskobalazs oh. didn't know that.

Comment: when i go to additional drivers it tells me that there ane no drivers

Comment: @OrEvron Yeah, as meskobalazs pointed out, there seem to be no other drivers in your specific case. His answer will help you most, I guess. I didn't delete this answer though, because in many other cases (including me) this is the solution.